# What is the correct way to find if any item in a one to many relationship has a flag set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have the following database schema

[image]

And I wanted to write a query that listed all Bill_Items, but included a flag that was true if any associated inventory items where marked with the CheckFlag bit, what would be the correct way to do it?

The way I thought of doing it is

```
select *, case when exists(select  CheckFlag
                            from inventoryitems 
                            inner join Linked_items on Item_code = ItemCode 
                            where Bill_Code = BillCode
                                  and CheckFlag = 1
                            ) 
                then 1 else 0 end as flagSet 
from Bill_items
```

However I am fairly certain I am not doing this the correct way, what is the way I should be doing a check like this?

Comment: What's not correct about this? Are you not getting the results you want, or do you think there's a more performant way to structure the query?

Comment: I feel that this would be non performant, it is performing N queries the inner select where N is the number of rows in Bill_Items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
     Bill_items.billcode
    ,max(cast(CheckFlag as int)) as flagSet 
from Bill_items
join Linked_items 
    on Bill_items.billcode = Linked_items.Bill_Code
join inventoryitems
    on Linked_items.Item_code = inventoryitems.ItemCode 
group by
     Bill_items.billcode
```

If you need to include Bill_items without inventoryitems try this:

```
select
     Bill_items.billcode
    ,max(isnull(cast(CheckFlag as int),0)) as flagSet 
from Bill_items
left join Linked_items 
    on Bill_items.billcode = Linked_items.Bill_Code
left join inventoryitems
    on Linked_items.Item_code = inventoryitems.ItemCode 
group by
     Bill_items.billcode
```

Here is a derived version joined onto bill items

```
select
     Bill_items.*
    ,isnull(_CheckFlags.flagSet,0) as flagSet
from Bill_items
left join (
    select
         Linked_items.Bill_Code
        ,max(cast(CheckFlag as int)) as flagSet 
    from Linked_items 
    join inventoryitems
        on Linked_items.Item_code = inventoryitems.ItemCode 
    group by
         Linked_items.Bill_Code
) _CheckFlags
    on Bill_items.billcode = _CheckFlags.Bill_Code
```

Try this for method without CAST:

```
select
     Bill_items.*
    ,isnull(_CheckFlags.flagSet,0) as flagSet
from Bill_items
left join (
    select
         Linked_items.Bill_Code
        ,CheckFlag as flagSet 
    from Linked_items 
    join inventoryitems
        on Linked_items.Item_code = inventoryitems.ItemCode
    where CheckFlag = 1
    group by
         Linked_items.Bill_Code
        ,CheckFlag
) _CheckFlags
    on Bill_items.billcode = _CheckFlags.Bill_Code
```

Comment: +1 for answering with correctly taking in to account the many to many relationships and generating the same results as the question's query, with the second query.

Comment: If other columns are needed you simply add them to the select list and group by clause. As long as CheckFlag is not added to either of these the results will not change. The * in the original query will only return all columns from the Bill_items table so that is all I included in my result set.

Comment: It is a reduced set for the example, and there are a LOT of referenced columns in Bill_item, I will have to test my old way and this way and see how the results are.

Comment: If you cannot group by all the fields you could derive this and join it to your query on Bill_items.billcode which should still be more performant than a subquery. This is not always the case but I try to avoid subqueries as much as I can.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a derived version joined onto a query of all Bill_items.

Comment: Hrm, I got back from my lunch to try it out and I ended up getting the error `Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.` Is it better to cast to int, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Cast should work, I edited the existing answers to include cast. I also added a method I believe will work without casting.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (the inner sub-query shall save you from adding all the columns in the `group by` clause) and would also be faster

```
SELECT 
  bi.*,
  temp.checkflag
FROM 
  bill_items bi
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT 
                max(ii.checkflag) as checkflag,
                li.bill_code
              FROM 
                linked_items li
                JOIN inventory_items ii ON ( ii.item_code = ii.itemCode AND ii.checkflag = 1 ) 
              GROUP BY
                li.bill_code
            ) as temp ON ( temp.bill_code = bi.billCode )
```

Comment: Would using a Inner join on the Linked_items-Inventory_items link be better for this due to Item_Code being a forgen key?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you don't just join the tables and use a `row_number` to return the first row for each `billcode`:

```
select billcode, flagset
from
(
  select b.*, -- replace this with your columns
    i.checkflag flagSet,
    row_number() over(partition by b.billcode order by i.CheckFlag desc) rn
  from Bill_items b
  left join Linked_items l
    on l.Bill_Code = b.BillCode
  left join inventoryitems i
    on l.Item_code = i.ItemCode
) d
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89f6d/3)

The `CheckFlag` is a bit so the result will be zero or one, there shouldn't be a need for the CASE.

Comment: What if a bill item doesn't have any linked items? It would be left out of the results, instead of being included with a 0 flag value.

Comment: Then you'd get duplicate records for bill items with multiple linked items.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I would start with joining instead of using the correlated subquery

Comment: My point is that your answers aren't generating the same result sets as the original query.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName You are right, my bad. I have edited my answer to include `row_number()`